# MC Home and random teleport on a vanilla server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How do I allow my server patrons to be able to have a home set to tp to and to be able to randomly teleport around the world?

i.e....Rendogs mc server

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far? We expect some own effort from askers, as said in the [tour] (which you read, so you should know).

Comment: Only stuff I have found is my modding my server, but with a modded server you can't have vanilla players on can you?

Comment: Firstly, of course you can. Secondly, you must do weird kinds of research, because just googling "minecraft teleport" gives you thousands of results that all tell you how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Look into running **Spigot**. It will provide you with a lot of options. Vanilla players can connect to a spigot server.

https://www.spigotmc.org/

Plugins can be found here:
https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/

Some random teleport plugins:

https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/random-teleport.53146/
https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/random-teleport.65483/